# Multimedia keyboard remapping

Tags: keyboard, remote, multimedia, xev

I have a G7BTS remote controller, which has both keyboard and multimedia buttons. Most of its buttons work well except "OK" button.

The OK button has a keycode 353, which means KEY_SELECT. But my ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize it.

Below are some researches I have done:

1. `sudo evtest`

output:

```
/dev/input/event9:  G7BTS Keyboard
/dev/input/event10: G7BTS Mouse
/dev/input/event11: G7BTS Consumer Control
/dev/input/event12: G7BTS System Control
```

2. `grep "" /sys/class/input/event11/device/id/*`

output:

```
/sys/class/input/event11/device/id/bustype:0005
/sys/class/input/event11/device/id/product:0041
/sys/class/input/event11/device/id/vendor:045e
/sys/class/input/event11/device/id/version:0300
```

3. `sudo evtest /dev/input/event11`

output:

```
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1640250050.701930, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0041
Event: time 1640250050.701930, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 353 (KEY_SELECT), value 1
Event: time 1640250050.701930, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

4. `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`

I tried to remap OK button to 'enter'.

60-keyboard.hwdb file content:

```
# G7BTS
evdev:input:b0005v045Ep0041*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c0041=enter
```

5. `sudo udevadm hwdb --test='evdev:input:b0005v045ep0041*'`

output:

```
KEYBOARD_KEY_c0041=enter
```

So far, I still cannot see any output in xev when I press OK button.

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

It took me several days to find out the solution, finally, I found the right way.

### Reference

Map scancodes to keycodes

#### Background

Version 11 of the X protocol only supports single-byte key codes. So key codes above 255 are ignored. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, so far, still uses version 11 of X protocol.

My G7BTS remote keyboard has a “OK” button. This button has a key code of 353. Within “xev”, nothing happens when this button is pressed.

#### Solution

By brief, the solution is to create a hwdb configuration file, which is used to remap certain keys to other keys.

##### udev

udev provides a builtin function called hwdb to maintain the hardware database index in /etc/udev/hwdb.bin. The database is compiled from files with .hwdb extension located in directories /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/, /run/udev/hwdb.d/ and /etc/udev/hwdb.d/. The default scancodes-to-keycodes mapping file is /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb.

Generic input devices (also USB keyboards) identified by the usb kernel modalias:

```
evdev:input:b<bus_id>v<vendor_id>p<product_id>e<version_id>-<modalias>
```

where <bus_id>, <vendor_id> and <version_id> are the 4-digit hex uppercase vendor, product and version IDs

How to find those ids above is the key

```
install hardinfo
sudo apt install hardinfo
software – System Profiler – Input Devices – G7BTS Comsumer Control
```

```
Device Information
 Name       G7BTS Comsumer Control
 Type       keyboard
 Bus        0x0005
 Vender     0x045e
 Product    0x0041
 Version    0x0300
```

Another import thing is to get the scan code of the “OK” button.

```
install evtest
sudo apt-get install evtest
sudo evtest
```

```
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:    Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:    Sleep Button
/dev/input/event2:    Power Button
/dev/input/event3:    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:    SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
/dev/input/event5:    TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
/dev/input/event6:    ThinkPad Extra Buttons
/dev/input/event7:    Video Bus
/dev/input/event8:    Integrated Camera: Integrated C
/dev/input/event9:    G7BTS Keyboard
/dev/input/event10:    G7BTS Mouse
/dev/input/event11:    G7BTS Consumer Control
/dev/input/event12:    G7BTS System Control
/dev/input/event13:    HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event14:    HDA Intel PCH Dock Mic
/dev/input/event15:    HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event16:    HDA Intel PCH Dock Headphone
/dev/input/event17:    HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event11:    HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event19:    HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
Select the device event number [0-19]: ^C
```

Pay attention to “/dev/input/event11”

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/event11
```

Then press “OK” button, and the output is below

```
Event: time 1640238746.775220, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value c0041
Event: time 1640238746.775220, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 353 (KEY_SELECT), value 0
Event: time 1640238746.775220, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

Pay attention to “value c0041“. This value c0041 is the scan code of “OK” button.

##### Make the hwdb file

Now, we have the ids and the scan code we need. Put them into the “Generic input devices (also USB keyboards) identified by the usb kernel modalias” above, and finally we have the configuration file G7BTS.hwdb below:

```
evdev:input:b0005v045Ep0041e0300*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_c0041=enter
```

In the context, the “OK” button is mapped into “enter” key. You can map it into any key you want.

##### Put file to destination

```
sudo mv G7BTS.hwdb /etc/udev/hwdb.d/
```

##### Update

```
sudo udevadm hwdb --update
sudo udevadm trigger --verbose
```

##### Test

```
sudo udevadm hwdb --test='evdev:input:b0005v045Ep0041e0300*'
```

result is

```
KEYBOARD_KEY_c0041=enter
```

#### The End

That is all the steps to remap keys. Those remapping still work after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I got an external keyboard working in Ubuntu 20.04 using the information from https://www.foell.org/justin/remapping-keyboard-keys-in-ubuntu-with-udev-evdev/

1. use `sudo evtest` to find the info about your keyboard, like:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x5 vendor 0x5ac product 0x24f version 0x11b
Input device name: "Keychron K6 Keyboard"
```

2. use `sudo evemu-describe` to find the properties of the keyboard, including the leading zeros. In the output you can find something like:

```
# Properties:
N: Keychron K6 Keyboard
I: 0005 05ac 024f 011b
```

3. create the .hwdb file like you did but **include all the leading 000**, and **put any hexadecimal symbols in uppercase** like:

```
# Input device ID: bus 0x5 vendor 0x5ac product 0x24f version 0x11b
# evdev:input:b<bus_id>v<vendor_id>p<product_id>e<version_id>-<modalias>
evdev:input:b0005v05ACp024F*
```

4. you don't have to reboot your system, just do:

```
$ sudo systemd-hwdb update
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

5. you can check if your keyboard has been mapped correctly using `$ udevadm info /dev/input/event20` (replace event20 with the event for your keyboard)

Comment: Please be a little careful with posting exact copy and paste answers throughout Ask Ubuntu. Answers should be carefully tailored to exactly fit the question being asked.